# Need help for insert data from multiple check-box-list into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

```
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList3.Items.Count + 1; i++)
             {
               if (CheckBoxList3.Items[i].Selected || CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Selected || CheckBoxList5.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    str1 += CheckBoxList3.Items[i].Text.ToString() + "," + CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Text.ToString() +"," + CheckBoxList5.Items[i].Text.ToString() + ",";
```

I receive the error call "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index". How to solve this issue?

What I want to do was collect the data from checkedbox in multiple check-box-list and combine together and store it into database.

Any suggestion or help would be great. Thanks

UPDATE : This is one of my check box list. The error point to my second line of the for loop.

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="900px">
            <asp:ListItem>Chicken</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Tomato</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Garlic</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: `CheckBoxList3.Items.Count + 1` should just be `CheckBoxList3.Items.Count` otherwise you'll try and access past the end of the array.

Comment: What is the data source of your check box list? Is it from SP or predefined in your code? Please specify this for us to help you better.

Comment: @Loocid i changed it but it still does't work

Comment: @RichardMarkBonifacio the item inside check box list is defined in the code.

Comment: The database your using?

Comment: @RichardMarkBonifacio I do not use any database. The item inside is defined as asp:list item at the design part.

Comment: Is there any error after removing +1?

Comment: @MasLoo the error still same "The index was out of range"

Comment: but your title says "Need help for insert data from multiple check-box-list into database", what DB you want it to save?

Comment: You're accessing different CheckBoxLists. Are you sure they're the same size? I mean all those have same number of items?

Comment: @MasLoo One of them have less one items, is that any other way to combine it?

Comment: Do loop through each of CheckBoxList items separately and then collect them in your string or wherever you need it. You need 3 loops through 3 CheckBoxLists.

Comment: @MasLoo You mean make it 3 if statement inside the for loop? Do you mind show one example?

Comment: Sorry about that, That's wrong. I changed my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your for loop like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList3.Items.Count; i++)
    if (CheckBoxList3.Items[i].Selected)
        str1 += CheckBoxList3.Items[i].Text.ToString() + ",";

for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList4.Items.Count; i++)
    if (CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Selected)
        str1 += CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Text.ToString() + ",";

for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList5.Items.Count; i++)
    if (CheckBoxList5.Items[i].Selected)
        str1 += CheckBoxList5.Items[i].Text.ToString() + ",";
```

**UPDATE**

@Caner LENGER has a good idea. But as I mentioned in the comment of his answer it's partially true, because `list.Min` returns minimum value of a list that in your case it's not gonna work. Why?

Imagine you have 3 CheckBoxLists that each one has 3 items in it except one of them that has 4. Using `list.Min` you'll get 3, No matter what's inside the 4th value of CheckBoxList.

So, I changed his code and here is the tested result:

```
public static string CombineCheckboxLists(params CheckBoxList[] list)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (CheckBoxList checkBoxList in list)
    {
        int counter = checkBoxList.Items.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            sb.Append(checkBoxList.Items[i].Selected ? checkBoxList.Items[i].Text + "," : "");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: you're welcom. Happy coding.

Comment: Also you can find below my generic code for future to apply which are matched by same indexes. (Answer edited)

Answer (score 1):

> **Wrong line 1:**  `for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList3.Items.Count + 1; i++`
>
> **Wrong line 2:** `CheckBoxList3.Items[i].Selected || CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Selected || CheckBoxList5.Items[i].Selected`
>
> **Wrong line 3:**  `str1 += CheckBoxList3.Items[i].Text.ToString() + "," + CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Text.ToString() +"," + CheckBoxList5.Items[i].Text.ToString() + ",";`

You need to change your for loop condition from `CheckBoxList3.Items.Count + 1` to `CheckBoxList3.Items.Count`

Also your condition checking only `CheckBoxList3.Items.Count` but you are using `CheckBoxList4.Items.Count` and `CheckBoxList5.Items.Count`

It seems `CheckBoxList4` and `CheckBoxList5` don't have enough item like CheckBoxList3.

Please Check your all individual CheckboxList objects to use same indexer.

Hope this helps.

//EDIT

Best practice:

```
string result = CombineCheckboxLists(checkBoxList1, checkBoxList2, checkboxlist3);

 private string CombineCheckboxLists(params CheckBoxList[] list)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        string result = string.Empty;
        if (list?.Length > 0)
        {
            int minItemsCount = list.Min(l => l.Items.Count);

            if (minItemsCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < minItemsCount; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(string.Join(",", list
                        .Where(l => l.Items[i].Selected)
                        .Select(l=> l.Items[i].Text)));

                    //if you want to merge all iteration via ",", please use following lines instead of above -- [marked as **] 
                    // ** //builder.Append($"{string.Join(",", list.Select(l => l.Items[i].Value))},");
                }
            }
        }

        result = builder.ToString();
        // ** // result = result.TrimEnd(',');

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I know the error come from different number of item in different check box list, do you mind show me the correct loop to do it?

Comment: That's a good idea. Except the `list.Min` returns minimum value of a numeric collection (in this case it returns length of smallest list). So, that's not the best way to get number of items in all CheckBoxLists and you would definitely lose some data.

Comment: @MasLoo Just i think he want to log same level items. He can convert the code to any format using a proper condition for CheckboxLists supplied as parameters ;)